Как получить пользователей из 1С в keycloak User Federation?
Собственно, задача такая: имеется база с пользователями в 1С и есть keycloak 24.0.3. И когда пользователь зарегистрируется через keycloak, данные должны синхронизироваться из базы 1С в базу keycloak.
Единственное поле, по которому может быть произведено сопоставление - поле СНИЛСА.
Возможно ли такое провернуть через User federation через LDAP или Kerberos проввайдеров, не прибегая к допиливанию keycloak?
Или есть готовые модули, которые чуть-чуть придётся отредактировать?

То есть, данные о пользователе уже есть в 1С, и при регистрации в системе keycloak туда должны попасть данные из 1С?
А что такое "keycloak", вкратце?

Вы имеете ввиду, Если юзер заходит в 1С с использованием keycloak, то ... Вам нужно сопоставить его с Пользователем в 1С ? Если так, то проще в 1С руками выставить Пользователя которому соответствует УЗ

@Sagittarius, единая точка входа. Как аутентификация через гугл аккаунт.

@santavital,  мне нужно, чтобы человеку, который зарегистрировался через web морду keycloak, получил все свои данные из 1с. Грубо говоря, есть база пользователей keycloak, у каждого есть поле с телефоном. Нужно, чтобы по сопоставлению номера телефона мне из 1С автоматом запросились данные и сохранились в базе keycloak, чтобы я мог потом вывести их в JWT токен для показа информации на сайтах и другой бизнес логики.

@Regear, в 1С есть Web-, HTTP- сервисы. Можно через них получать нужные данные.

@Regear, рекомендую ориентироваться на следующую схему: когда пользователь заходит в 1С, в 1С получаем все УЗ Keycloak; сопоставляем есть ли УЗ текущего Пользователя, если есть записываем обратно в Keycloak атрибут УЗ (необходимые из 1С данные) Такой вариант наиболее компактный, весь код в 1С;
Альтернативный вариант, на стороне 1С создать HTTP-сервис, получающий на вход данные для идентификации Пользователя, возвращающий необходимые данные; На стороне Keycloak нам нужен скрипт, который периодически запрашивает 1С HTTP-сервис получает все данные целиком, затем обновляет УЗ Keycloak

Я думаю использовать альтернативный вариант, ибо 1с - не единственный источник данных для пользователей. Осталось разобраться, как это сделать на практике.ю..
